# Python listcomp with generators

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to add words generated by a generator to a list if it is unique in the list for a maximum of 10 times.

```
word_list = []
for i in range(10):
    next_word = next(test)
    if next_word not in word_list:
        word_list.append(next_word)
```

This is what I tried for list comprehension

```
word_list = [next(test) for next(test) in range(10) if next(test) not in word_list]
```

I encountered two problems

- I can't check if the word is already in the list inside the listcomp
- Every time I use next(test), it newly generates so I can't add the next generator

How would I implement the first code snippet with listcomp?

Comment: can you provide the code for the generator?

Comment: @bravosierra99 The generator returns a string for every next(test). Is the code for the generator relevant here?

Comment: @Umuko Yes, in order for those who want to help you to make reproducible source code. Have a look at [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it means I don't have to generate it myself, and that I fully understand your problem.  in this case the list comprehension completely depends on the generator, so yea it's important and relevant.

Comment: in this case I specifically want to know if your generator terminates or not.  It'll be important for the solution.

Comment: Do you need to generate 10 unique items by keep pulling from generator until you reach 10 uniques or just try 10 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's solve the generator issue. As you mention, you want to use next(test) only once in each iteration. The simplest solution is to loop over test, which is exactly like calling next:

```
word_list = [s for _, s in zip(range(10), test)]
```

This code will take the first 10 words from the generator. Now, you want it to take only the unique values. Instead of checking that in the list comp, you can turn it into set, if you don't mind the order:

```
word_list = set([s for _, s in zip(range(10), test)])
```

If you do mind the order, you can use the [OrderSet recipe](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/3b27230f418b714bc9a0f897cb8ea189c3515e99/recipes/Python/576696_OrderedSet_with_Weakrefs/recipe-576696.py), or even simpler to use the OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict    
word_list = [t[0] for t in OrderedDict({s:_ for _, s in zip(range(10), test)})]
```

And you'll end up with the same output like in your for loop. 
This solution isn't so readble, and I must say I would prefer to use the old nice for loop instead.

Or even better as @tobias_k suggested:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import islice
word_list = list(OrderedDict({s:s for s in islice(test, 0, 10)}))
```

Comment: Or just `list(OrderedDict(...))`? Also, could use `itertools.islice` instead of `zip` with `range`

Comment: I think the OP wants to get 10 unique items each time regardless of number of generator cycles and not a unique set of 10 generated items.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of a guess but I think you really want to pull next 10 unique values from a generator and in that case it might be tricky with list comprehension and even your example with loop won't really do that. To get 10 next unique values:

```
 def gen():
     for n in [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]:
         yield n

 l = []
 g = gen()
 while len(l) < 11:
     try:
         v = next(g)
     except StopIteration:
         break
     if v not in l:
         l.append(v)
 print l
```

Answer (score 0):

yo can use genetors like that dont need range() func:

```
word_list = [item for item in test if item not in word_list]
```

or if you need to call n items use itertools:

```
import itertools

word_list = [item for item in itertools.islice(test,10) if item not in word_list]
```

or you can use zip func:

```
word_list = [item for item,ret in zip(test,range(10)) if item not in word_list]
```

or if you want to get first n items unique i think you cant do that with listcomp